# Android emulator cannot access remote server

Tags: php, android

Currently have two computers. Computer A is running an android emulator, while  computer B is acting as the server. Despite numerous attempts, the android emulator cannot connect to the remote server. I originally kept getting

> Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

But now I'm getting

```
           W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
           ....
           ....
           ....
           Error Occurred, in try statement (Server Connection Code)
```

The following is what I have on the server

```
    try { 
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dname=$database;port=3306", $username, $password);
          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

where

```
      $hostname = "192.168.1.152";   // Computer B
```

This is unfamiliar territory for me, does anybody know the solution?

Comment: by default mysql usually does not accept requests from outside the local network, you have to tell it if you want that.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but its actually a LAN connection. Both computer A and computer B are in the same location. The server is not public.

Comment: ok, still double check the user privlages